# How to find total acceleration data from X,Y,Z axis from mpu9250 when vibration is produced in the accelerometer

Tags: c, accelerometer, esp32

I want to find acceleration data when small vibration produced in mpu9250 module....Total acceleration means the acceleration produced by the vibration from X,Y and Z axis of accelerometer.

```
  float r =  sqrt((IMU.getAccelX_mss()*IMU.getAccelX_mss()) +(IMU.getAccelY_mss()*IMU.getAccelY_mss())+(IMU.getAccelZ_mss()*IMU.getAccelZ_mss()));
    Serial.println(r);
```

Here i have tried to find resultant of all axis but output is NOT as expected.

Comment: Well what did you expect? And what is the output? Your formula is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: Try splitting it into multiple lines, and assign the X,Y,Z values to variables. As it is, you're potentially calling some functions twice as often as you need to.